# Document WriteIn If Location Window Search

Tags: window.location

I'm trying to do a `document.writeln` function based on a keyword search. If the user searches for the terms:

`**widget xyz`
`xyz **widget**`
`my **widget**` works

The searches are currently displayed this url format:

```
?Search=**widget**+xyz
?Search=xyz+**widget**
?Search=my+**widget**+
```

works

I would like to perform `document.writeln` on pages with the key word `**widget**` included in the search.

Here is where I'm at:

*EXAMPLE 1:)*

```
if (location.search == "**widget**") 
   document.writeln("\n<style type='text/css'>CUSTOM CSS</style>\n\n");
```

*EXAMPLE 2:)*

```
  if (location.search == "**widget**"!= -1) 
       document.writeln("\n<style type='text/css'>CUSTOM CSS</style>\n\n");
```

The 2nd example kind of works, but shows the `WriteIn` on other keyword search results as well. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what exactly do you think should happen with `location.search == "widget"!= -1`? You need to learn about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: I think I solved my own problem, at least for my site....

(location.pathname == "/SearchResults.asp" && window.location.href.indexOf("widget") != -1)&&document.writeln("\n<style type='text/css'>CSS</style>\n\n")

Comment: Thanks to Operator Precedence ;) I learned the strict AND